# Android application is not working in lower version like Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to developing an application that work in all android version like API level 23 as well as API level 8.While debugging the application it is working perfectly on latest version api, but not working on lower version like Gingerbread.

I try to change `minSdkVersion`, but this did not solve the issue.

**While debugging in lower version it showing error**

> "Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars
>   that don't match the current version (dexopt error). In order to
>   proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application."

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.linphone"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion
    }
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
      />
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace!

Comment: Installing org.linphone
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/org.linphone"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/org.linphone
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall org.linphone
Unknown failure  @ Anggrayudi H

Comment: Have you tried to clear the app's data and uninstall it manually?

Comment: the app is not yet installed in "Gingerbread" and  am trying to install in "Gingerbread". So ...

Answer (score 0):

You are using gradle, so you should remove uses-sdk declaration form the manifest.xml - gradle adds it it self. Then change minSdkVersion in the build.gradle to equal or lower than your desired one.

Comment: I remove uses-sdk declaration form the manifest.xml. but still its not running, it showing "Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error). In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application." @piotrpo

Comment: What is your system version (you have 9 in gradle, but you asked for 8 in question?

Comment: the application is not working in version below ice cream sandwich.GingerBread API is 10, I try to install it in GingerBread but its not working  @piotrpo

Answer (score 0):

Enable your `proguard`, its probably caused by dex file. It happens when dex file gets larger then buffer size( i.e. contains more than 65k methods).

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app has reached 65k methods limit. There are few solutions:

1. Shrink your code with [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). From the docs:

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Because ProGuard makes your application harder to reverse engineer, it is important that you use it when your application utilizes features that are sensitive to security like when you are [Licensing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

Enable it on `build.gradle` of your `app` module:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

You can add your own ProGuard custom rule, [read here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-steps-to-enable-ProGuard-in-Android-Studio).

2. Update SDK Build Tools to the latest version.
3. Build your app with [MultiDex technique](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Additionally, your `apply plugin: 'android'` must be changed to `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this trying to test on an emulator. My solution was to give the emulator more memory and storage. It appears to be an issue when building with new (ART) tools and deploying to Dalvik.